# [iPhone:interface builder]switching between views when clicking on a button

Tags: iphone

please i have a view containing 3 buttons and i want to switch to another views when clicking:
button1->view A
button2->View B
button3->View C
i googled and i didn't found any tutorials to do so, please help, THX in advance :)

Comment: i search on youtube and google something like : switching views when clicking buttons, but i got tutorials not adaptable to my problem, they use sometimes navigation controller and sound don't go with my case. THX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that by putting a UIButton on the view in IB and hook that button up with a method that puts a new view on screen with button 2 on it. It should be pretty straight forward.

Take a basic tutorial on iPhone development and you learn how to do stuff like that in a day.

Here's one from [apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/01_Overview.html)

Comment: Hi aneshqst, thnx a lot for your answer, however, the link you just give me doesn't explain switching view when clicking buttons, i know do basic stuff and i want to learn how this can be done, THX again

Comment: If you want to know how to - switch view when clicking buttons - you need to know how to ptu a button on screen, make a method get called when that button is clicked and then how to put a view on screen. Following the tutorial will not answer your specific problem, but something much better, it'll teach you general stuff that'll make you capable of solving your problem (and similar problems!) on your own.